# c#: how to quickly insert a character into string in front of any occurrences of special combinations of characters?

Tags: c#, string, insert

I have a string where I need to escape any occurrences of special combinations of characters. In other words, I need to stick a "\" in front any occurrence of any such combination. Most combinations are actually single characters (e.g a double quote or a backslash) but some are multi-character (e.g. "&&"). One approach is to create an array of strings with these combinations, loop over them and run a `String.Replace()`, with the backslash being checked the last to avoid recursive escaping. But is there a better (more elegant/quick/etc) way of doing it? Thx

Comment: You should repalce the backslash first, not last, otherwise you'll e.g. replace "&&" with "\&&", and then with "\\&&", which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: can you have &&& in your string ? and if yes, is it for \&&& or &\&& ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your idea of Replace but using an [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) instead ([much better perfomance](http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) for this.

```
var input = @"abc'def&&aa\cc""ff";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"'|&&|""|\\", m => @"\" + m); // => "abc\'def\&&aa\\cc\"ff"
```

Comment: Regex.Replace performance are very slow, even then String.Replace

Comment: It depends. If you need to do it only few times and not in a loop, then it is fine. the question asked for multiple values of better: elegant, quick... This is more elegant and less error prone then String.Replace where you need to take care of replacement ordering (e.g. "\" should be last, what if both & and && need to be replaced, etc...). what you talk about is premature optimization. Besides, if you have 5 things to escape you need to call String.Replace 5 times and Regex.Replace just once.

Comment: I think I need efficiency more than anything else, but thanks anyway

Comment: Just make sure you measure. You might be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

you can just take your entire string and run String.Replace() for each replacement type you want to do, As far as I know that is the quickest/most elegant way to do it. Thats why it is a built in method.

Comment: The biggest problem with Replace is that it creates more string copies each time it is called. This can often lead to measurable performance problems in large projects. It's way better to use StringBuilder.

Comment: I guess that would depend on the size of the string being used also, anything under 256 bytes or 4 or 5 replacements is not going to noticeably degrade performance. But yes you are correct as String object is immutable yada yada yada